# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6x}}{\sqrt{2}(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6x}}{\sqrt{2}(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)}$.

My solution goes as follows:

> Given, $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6x}}{\sqrt{2}(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)}$.
>
> So,$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{3}^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6x}}{\sqrt{2}(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6(\frac{\pi}{3}+h)}}{\sqrt{2}(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{3}-h)}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2\pi+6h)}}{\sqrt{2}(-h)}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6h}}{\sqrt{2}(-h)}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin3h}{\sqrt{2}(-h)}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{3\sin3h}{(-3h)}\\&=-3.\end{align}$$

However the answer given in the book is $3$. Where is the problem occurring ? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\sqrt{1-cos6x}}{\sqrt{2}\frac{\pi}{3}-x}$ is undefined because the left limit and right limit are not equal. You are taking the right limit, your book is taking the left limit.

Comment: @Dan so, the limit shouldn't exist actually, right?

Comment: That's right. Either the question is flawed, or the answer in the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The wrong step is,$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6h}}{\sqrt{2}(-h)}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin3h}{\sqrt{2}(-h)}$$

---

The numerator of the limit on the left side is $\sqrt{1-\cos(6h)}$ which simplifies as follows:
$$\sqrt{1 - \cos(6h)} = \sqrt{2 \sin^2(3h)} = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\sin^2(3h)} = \sqrt{2} |\sin(3h)|.$$

You have incorrectly assumed that $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)} = \sin(x)$ but it equals $|\sin x|$.

---

Using $\sqrt{2} |\sin(3h)|$ instead in the numerator, we have:

$$\begin{align} L &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos6h}}{\sqrt{2}(-h)}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2}|\sin3h|}{\sqrt{2}(-h)} \\& =-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|\sin3h|}{h}\cdot \frac33  \\& =-3 \lim_{3h\to 0}\frac{|\sin3h|}{3h} \end{align}$$

This limit doesn't exist. So the answer is "Undefined".